# Install specific package version (available on Launchpad)

Tags: apt, ppa

I'm trying to pin packages installed through `apt` on Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately older versions of packages are removed very quickly it seems, so e.g.:

```
apt install -y git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.6
```

yields:

```
E: Version '1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.6' for 'git' was not found
```

I *can* see this exact same package version on Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.6 and I can download the `.deb` file and install it.

How can I tell `apt` to search on the Launchpad repository for this package? Is that even possible? If going to the builds page it seems to be listed under `~ubuntu-security` which is a private PPA which I cannot add:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-security/ppa
Adding private PPAs is not supported currently
```

(But I'm not sure if I'm using this correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Launchpad's historic library is not an apt-compatible repository. Nor can it be made so by user actions.

There are no known tools to make Launchpad compatible with apt. (That would be a support nightmare!)

You must manually browse and download the debs you want.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to find a way around this I found that Debian maintains snapshots of their complete package repository (e.g. http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230804T031641Z/). You can add this snapshot as a source for apt - and this should (I believe) always lead to the exact same packages being installed:

```
echo 'deb [trusted=yes] http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20230804T031641Z/ bullseye main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snapshot.list && \
    printf "Package: r-*\nPin: origin snapshot.debian.org\nPin-Priority: 990\n" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/snapshot && \
    apt -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

When now doing `apt install -y curl` this should always get you `7.74.0-1.3+deb11u7`.

Unfortunately Debian snapshots are (in the short time that I've been testing it) have been very slow and unreliable; so it would be great if someone would make a commercial version of this.